# Подскажите ошибку в CSS

Tags: css3, ratingbar

Подскажите пожалуйста, при наведении на рейтинг в виде звезд на сайте 
https://binaryoptionsdominator.com/brokers/20-belkovye-obolochki.html
звезды скачут. не могу разобраться в чем дело, подскажите как можно поправить?

Comment: dle приятный шаблон , звёздный рейтинг готовый есть на so

Comment: Google Chrome Версия 70.0.3538.77 - ничего не скачет